# How to create a special OR statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a program where it keeps asking you for your first, middle and last name in a loop until you enter `'EXIT'` or `'exit'` as the last name. The `||` statement operator I'm using here isn't working and I can't seem to find the answer. Any ideas?

```
var FirstName = '' ;
var MiddleName = '' ;
var LastName = '' ;
var FullName = '' ;

while (LastName != 'EXIT' || LastName != 'exit' ) {

    FirstName = prompt ('What is your first name');
    MiddleName = prompt ('What is your middle name');
    LastName = prompt ('What is your last name');

    FullName = FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName;

    alert ('Welcome, ' + FullName);
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: The condition will always be true due to ordinary `or` logic. Do `LastName.toLowerCase() !== 'exit'` instead

Comment: That condition is always true. Since no matter what value `LastName` has, it must be unequal to one of those two things. It looks like you may want a logical and `&&` instead of an or.

Answer (score 2):

you need to check your boolean logic.  here is a working code sample:

```
var FirstName = '' ;
var MiddleName = '' ;
var LastName = '' ;
var FullName = '' ;

while (LastName != 'EXIT' && LastName != 'exit' ) { /* updated */

    FirstName = prompt ('What is your first name');
    MiddleName = prompt ('What is your middle name');
    LastName = prompt ('What is your last name');

    FullName = FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName;

    alert ('Welcome, ' + FullName);
}
```

`!A AND !B` instead of `!A OR !B` -- the latter is always true in your case because you are comparing the same variable to two different strings.